# The number of character slots per server

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is it possible to have 16 characters on 1 server? I know that normally (as a subscriber) you get 12 slots. But can you buy more than 12 slots per server?

This way I can get all advanced classes on both imperial en republic side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Patch 4.0](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/10202015/game-update-4.0-knights-fallen-empire-early-access), the limit for subscribers is now 40.  Instant Level 60 character tokens are now sold on the Cartel Market, which come with a character slot (in addition to the character-slot-only item).

---

Diego is correct, but the devs are being hyperbolic.  [The exact server limit is 22](http://www.swtor.com/community/showpost.php?p=5695538&postcount=69), which I don't consider ridiculously high by any means.  The total allowance of 350 characters across all servers is indeed quite high, however.

I got 16 on my server via the merge of 2 servers where I had 8 each.  The devs have confirmed that I'd need to buy the extra 4 (over 12) first if I ever wanted to move past 16, so there's that.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading an official post from the devs that the limit is "ridiculously high"; making it virtually unlimited.

Obviously, you'll have to buy slots from the cartel market. Don't know if you can buy them from the GTN.

Answer (score -1):

22 character slots is the limit per server.  I have unlocked them all.  Tried to unlock 23, it said I had the maximum.